# A question about marking favorites

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

Is there a provision so that the questions that one marks as favorites be available for his own reference as a list? If one marks a question as favorite it is usually because he/she finds it interesting and would want to refer to it from time to time.

Is this functionality already available? Or if, as is probable, I am missing out on something, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the list](https://stackoverflow.com/users/452307?tab=favorites) of the questions you have marked as favorites.

Comment: @RedDwight: Yes i could see that list but does it contain all the entries marked as favs till date? Actually I was pretty sure I had marked a few Q's as favs and today while looking up I couldnt find them there.

Comment: That's probably because the titles of the questions *have been edited* since you marked them as favorites.

Comment: ahh....:( seems like all hard work undone! Title editions on Favs should be taken care..shouldn't they?